# OpenOffice Calc Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc, openoffice-basic

I want to write a simple function to be used in OpenOffice Calc.

It would return true if the cell's value contains a substring, e.g.

```
function contains(string, substring) {

    return (string.indexOf(substring) > -1);
}
```

But I can't find any documentation or examples on that.

Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: i think adding the code to a new module and will make it available to cell formulas just like the built-ins

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work.  I added a simple function `function get411() { return 411; }` then in a cell I typed `=get411()` but got an error `#NAME?`

Answer (score 1):

Calc only accepts functions written in Basic.  See this thread for a more complete answer: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=30664#p158532